# All Child Nodes in XML are linked to a Parent Node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to fix a piece of code that is not doing what I want it to do. The code was left by an engineer who claimed it was working perfectly. He has been using XPATH instead of Linq, so for the short term I'm looking for a solution based on XPATH.

I've searched the web, but am unable to convert what I've found  into a working solution.

The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderId>6175</OrderId>
        <OrderNumber>6175</OrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>2016-08-19 13:17:41</OrderDate>
        <OrderLineItems>
            <ItemName>Name of Item</ItemName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Meta/>
        </OrderLineItems>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

The script he created with Visual Studio 2008 that concerns reading the XML looks like:

```
   public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string filename = Variables.strFileInLoop;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);


        // loop orders
        foreach (XmlNode shipmentNode in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Orders/Order"))
        {
            OutputOrdersBuffer.AddRow();
            String OrderId = GetNodeText("OrderId", shipmentNode).Trim();
            OutputOrdersBuffer.OrderId = OrderId;
            OutputOrdersBuffer.OrderNumber = GetNodeText("OrderNumber", shipmentNode).Trim();
            OutputOrdersBuffer.OrderDate = GetNodeText("OrderDate", shipmentNode).Trim();
            String replace = @"C:\Projects\Customername\IN\";
            OutputOrdersBuffer.FileName = filename.Replace(replace, "");

                foreach (XmlNode OrderLineItemNode in shipmentNode.SelectNodes("/Orders/Order/OrderLineItems"))
                {
                    OutputOrderLinesBuffer.AddRow();
                    OutputOrderLinesBuffer.OrderId = OrderId;
                    OutputOrderLinesBuffer.ItemName = GetNodeText("ItemName", OrderLineItemNode).Trim();
                    OutputOrderLinesBuffer.Quantity = GetNodeText("Quantity", OrderLineItemNode).Trim();
                    OutputOrderLinesBuffer.Meta = GetNodeText("Meta", OrderLineItemNode).Trim();

                }

        } 
    }
```

What happens when we try to import an XML with multiple orders is that the code attaches all OrderLineItems to all Orders.

So if there are 10 unique orders in the file with 2 OrderLineItems it put out 10 Orders with 20 OrderLineItems each.

As I said, I've looked everywhere (I think) but am unable to convert what I've found to a solution where the OrderLineItems are only linked to the order they belong to.

Comment: Maybe you should use OutputOrdersBuffer.OutputOrderLinesBuffer.AddRow();and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration within an order uses an *XPath* expression

```
/Orders/Order/OrderLineItems
```

that goes through the entire document every time, as the starting `/` in  indicates. This is why all order line items are included in all orders.

Changing the *XPath* expression to take `shipmentNode` as the context item, which happens implicitly if the *XPath* expression does not begin with a `/`, and navigating from there to its `OrderLineItems` children should help:

```
foreach (XmlNode OrderLineItemNode in shipmentNode.SelectNodes("OrderLineItems"))
```

An analogy with a file system on the command line usually helps when starting with *XPath*: the context item behaves like a working directory, and one can either change the directory with an absolute path (starting with `/`), or with a relative path to the current directory (starting with `./`, which also works in *XPath*). Of course *XPath* is different as it is set-oriented, but this analogy helps getting into the right mindset for navigation.

Comment: Thanks! That works! I have been searching for a couple of days and I figured that it had to be something in the Xpath expression, but never could figure out what. Just tried a file with 25 orders and a total of 28 lines and instead of getting 700 orderlines the output is what I needed! Thanks a million!!!